# How to open next bootstrap tab automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, bootstrap-modal

I have an modal; which does the count. After the count the modal closes. What I want to achieve how to close the next bootstrap soon when modal closes.

Here is HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs namelocationtable">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#one">one></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#two">two></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#three">three></a></li>
    <div id="one" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h1>One</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="tab-pane fade in">
      <h1>Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="tab-pane fade in">
      <h1>Three</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

**I do something in tab 1- modal appear; but when modal close; I want automatically to going to tab 2.**

**Jquery**

```
//opent the confirmation modal
$("#location-confirm-model").modal('show');

//Timer function and the ajax request. 
function count_down_timer_function() {
  var sec = 5
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
      if (sec == 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $("#timer-container").text('Saving details, please wait...');
        $("#location-confirm-model").modal('hide');
        console.log(1);
        $('.namelocationtable > .active').next('li').find('a');
        console.log(2);
        console.log(3);
      }
      $('#timer-container span').text(sec--);
    },
    1000);
  //Cancel count down and text
  $('.cancel-fill').click(function() {
    //Stop the countdown
    clearInterval(timer);
    //Reset timer
    $('#timer-container span').text('5');
  });
  setInterval(timer);
}
count_down_timer_function();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using bootstrap 3 (please clarify what bootstrap version you're using), you can do

```
$('#location-confirm-model').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#two"]').tab('show');
})
```

Comment: Thank you.  @Giacomo. This has worked.  Can I ask something else. The nav tabs will be generated dynamically in foreach loop. What is the best way to keep closing modal and going the next tab; and if the tab is last one; don't do anything

Comment: Sorry, i can't provide an aswer to this unless i see the code that creates tabs or what's the structure of dinamically created tabs.

To give a direction, during tabs creation, you can assign a class to all modals but last one and a data-attribute that refers to the next tab (that should be opened when modal gets closed).
After that, set the event listener and its function with proper edits to achive dynamic behaviour.